# I don't obtain change color of AppCompat

Tags: android

I'm having the same problem, but I generate a theme via X and after add into my project and I did the correctly references in my `styles.xml`, however don't work.

My manifest.xml is this:

`<uses-sdk 
 android:minSdkVersion="8" 
 android:targetSdkVersion="21" />`

Was generated the file below in http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator

styles_custom.xml, where add in my res/values/styles.xml:

`<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> </style>`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_custom</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.custom</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.custom</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.custom</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.custom</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.custom</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_custom</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_custom</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.custom</item>

</style>
```

And in res/value-v14/styles.xml

```
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
     <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_custom</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.custom</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.custom</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.custom</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.custom</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.custom</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_custom</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_custom</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.custom</item>
</style>
```

Well someone can help me, or give me the best directions, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AppCompat is a library project. You need to reference the library project in your android project. So first you need dowload the library through SDK manager .

To download the Support Library through the SDK Manager:-

refer this link:-  https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

In this above link read the topic :-Adding Libraries with resources ( It inlcudes so many steps that why I am giving the link )

After completing these steps :-

you can Add the library to your application project:

Step 1:-  In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.

Step2:- In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select Android.

Step 3:- In the Library pane, click the Add button.

Step 4:- Select the library project and click OK. For example, the appcompat project should be listed as android-support-v7-appcompat.

Step 5:- In the properties window, click OK

note :-If your app is using the Support Library for compatibility on devices running versions lower than Android 3.0, your custom theme should use Theme.AppCompat theme (or one of its descendants) as your parent theme.

Comment: My real issue was solved

Instead name="android:action...." it was name="action...." on file generate to http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator "res/values/style.custom.xml".

Tks.